# gallery to directory Php showing only the last 4 images

Tags: php, directory, gallery

I need to create a full page gallery showing only the last 4 images from a directory, i don't have idea how to introduce only the last 4 images saved in the directory, any idea?

```
<?php
$directory= "img";
$dirint = dir($directory);

while (($archivo = $dirint->read()) !== false){

    if (!preg_match('/gif/i', $archivo)
       || !preg_match('/jpg/i', $archivo)
       || !preg_match('/png/i', $archivo)) {

        for($x = 0; $x < 3; $x++) {
            echo '<img src="'.$directory."/".$archivo.'">'."\n";
            echo "<br>";
            $x++;
         }
    }
}

$dirint->close();

?>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a database to keep track of the photos? This way you could simply do a query that will limit it to the last 4. For example `SELECT imgPath FROM gallery ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4`

Comment: ok i need that application working without any database, i just need take the las 4 images. Thanks

Comment: could you possibly delete the oldest image once a new one is made so that you only ever have a total of 4 images in your folder?

Comment: sorry i need to keep all the images in the folder...
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i resolve my problem with a slice to the array dirint, thanks for the help here my solution:

```
<?php 
$img_dir = "THEPATHTOYOURDIRECTORY";
$images = scandir($img_dir);
$imageslast = array_slice($images,-4,6);
rsort($imageslast);
```

with imagelast i make a slice to the array counting the "." and ".." i sorted in reverse to take the last image.